# Hint on graphical element

Tags: android, android-layout, tooltip, hint

I have a layout which includes few graphical elements and I want to put on them some User Hints. Whenever an user touches an element, a Hint about the element is shown.

How can this be done on Android?

Comment: This is not related to the IDE you use. What you are looking for, is a tooltip, a little highlighted text that is shown when you hover over a component (not click on it)

Comment: i can hover with a mouse, but i dont know how to hover with my finger on an app.

Comment: i can give you an example of an app which use some similar "tooltips", try to take a look at HungiFungi app on the googleplay store. when you touch the little skull icon, you get a message of "poisonous mushroom" ... other icons return different messages ... i want to implement such tooltips for my graphical elements. Any ideea where to start?